# Déjà Dup won't back up ~/.config/nautilus-actions

Tags: 14.04, permissions, nautilus, backup, deja-dup

I'm a mostly-noob with Ubuntu. Running 14.04 LTS 64-bit.

I use Déjà Dup to backup my entire Home folder, daily, to an external 32GB SanDisk USB flash drive.

But after every backup, Déjà Dup tells me:

"Could not back up the following files. Please make sure you are able to open them."

The folder that won't backup: "/home/username/.config/nautilus-actions"

Question: Should I worry about this? Is it important that I successfully backup this folder/file? If so, then how do you advise? If it isn't important, then what am I losing by *not* backing it up? And in that case, how do I configure Déjà Dup so that it stops annoyingly telling me that it failed to backup this folder/file?

(I already tried changing the folder's/file's permissions to make it owner-executable, assuming that would give Déjà Dup access. But after I did that and logged back in, I got an error report. I'd apparently screwed with my system. Don't know how to look up the specifics of that error report — if that info would help, could you advise me on how to retrieve it?)

Thanks a billion.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my own problem. Answer was [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-actions/+bug/1000543).

TL;DR - Change the folder's permissions by typing `$ chmod 755 ~/.config/nautilus-actions` in terminal.

I found the answer in a post from 2012. Would be nice to know why this weird bug showed up again.